# How can I step into library code using the VS Code debugger in a Typescript/Node.js project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a Node.js project written in Typescript with the following dependency:

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@uniswap/smart-order-router": "^2.5.15",
```

From this library package I import some stuff in my project:

```
import { AlphaRouter, ... } from '@uniswap/smart-order-router'
```

And then use it like this:

```
const routeToRatioResponse: SwapToRatioResponse = await router.routeToRatio(
token0Balance,
token1Balance,
p,
{
  ratioErrorTolerance: new Fraction(5, 100),
  maxIterations: 1,
},
{
   swapOptions: {
     recipient: wallet.address,
     slippageTolerance: new Percent(5, 100),
     deadline: deadlineValue
   },
   addLiquidityOptions: {
     recipient: wallet.address
   }
 }
)
```

I have a breakpoint set on that first line above, at the call to `router.routeToRatio()`. When using the VS Code debugger, execution stops correctly at that line. But then when I click 'Step Into', I do not step into this function at all but instead go to the line after this whole function call.

The library project is written in Typescript. The code is here: https://github.com/Uniswap/smart-order-router. Note that the `tsconfig.json` for it has `inlineSourceMap` as true here: https://github.com/Uniswap/smart-order-router/blob/main/tsconfig.json#L9.

I don't seem to have the TS source for the library project in my `node_modules` dir. When I Ctrl-click on the function name, VS Code takes me to `./node_modules/@uniswap/smart-order-router/build/main/src/routers/alpha-router/alpha-router.d.ts` (which has no implementation code, only a class declaration), not to a file called `alpha-router.ts`. Digging around under `node_modules` I seem not to have that file.

[This answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231441/vs-code-debug-ts-code-when-stepping-into-a-library-function-in-the-node-js-debu) mentions the library project should have the `sourceRoot` set in the `tsconfig.json`, which it does not. I do not own the library project though, so I can't change anything there.

(Edit 1) Here's my `launch.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "type": "node",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/foo/src/index.ts",
        "request": "launch",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - foo/tsconfig.json",
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/foo"
    }
]
}
```

(Edit 2): Per the comments so far, I now have the dependencies I'm interested in debugging installed (in the `npm install` sense) as local folders. `package.json` looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@uniswap/smart-order-router": "file:../smart-order-router",
    ...
```

`tsconfig.json` has `"allowJs"` missing. I had to install some of the dependency's dependencies directly in my `package.json`. The code now builds with tsc without errors (without having to change any paths to imports in the TS sources), but now the debugger is completely broken.

The debugger stops at a breakpoint on the very first line of my `index.ts` and will step over lines ok for a bit but then execution stops here without any error: `node_modules/antlr4ts/index.js`

The only thing on the debug console in VSC is:

```
/home/e/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node ./node_modules/antlr4ts/index.js
```

Comment: What does your launch.json file look like? Are you using a skipFiles spec?

Comment: Added above. Nope, no skipFiles except "<node_internals>/**".

Comment: Have you tried cloning the lib repository and then npm install it from your local files?

Comment: Yep, tried that, but it broke my project. npm install worked, but then the IDE had red lines all over the place for the dependencies of the packages I installed, so I backed out of that approach.

Comment: Tried again with the local imports. I was able to fix the red lines for the imports in my own sources by using import { AlphaRouter, ... } from './smart-order-router/src/index', but that just uncovered 600 more problems when all the lib sources got built ("cannot find module...", "property x does not exist on type y", etc.)